# How wait for data(Array) from server and then push something into it in js?

Tags: javascript

I have problem with my code, problem is i get array from server with async function (getData()) and then i want push one object into it but it doesn't work and have error like this :

```
sandbox.js:61 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'push')
    at submitData (sandbox.js:61)
    at handleInputs (sandbox.js:44)
    at HTMLButtonElement.<anonymous> (sandbox.js:35)
```

and the code is here :

```
var dataBase;

const getData = async() => {
    const url = 'http://localhost:8080/readData';
    const res = await fetch(url);
    const data =  awair res.json();
    dataBase = data;
}

const handleInputs = () => {
    if (userName.value === "" && password.value === "" && repeatPassword.value === "" && checkTerms.checked) {
        alert('Please fill the input');
    } else {
        if (password.value === repeatPassword.value) {
            getData();
            submitData();
            renderUser();
            form.reset();
        } else {
            alert('Password does not match with repeat password input')
        }

    }
}

const submitData = () => {
    let userObj = {
        userName: userName.value,
        password: password.value,
        id: countId++
    }

    dataBase.push(userObj); // problem here
    sendData();
}
```

and how can i fix it ?

Comment: You need to await getData(); But ideally you should pass all variables to the functions which you want to use and not use global variables because it makes it harder to reason about how those impure functions mutate the state of your objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I have removed the functions not declared here for now. You can add it later.

**You are getting this error because you have not initialized database with any value, here an array**

I am returning **Promise** to wait till the user is fetched.

***Note:** You were having the same variable **dataBase** for saving newly fetched data. I have created a new data variable for saving newly fetched data and database variable for saving it for further use.*

```js
let newData;
let dataBase =[];

const getData = () => { 
    return new Promise(async(resolve, reject) => {
        const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1';
        const res = await fetch(url);
        const data =  await res.json();
        console.log(data);
        newData = data;
        resolve();
    })
}

const handleInputs = async () => {
    await getData();
    submitData();
    console.log("database", dataBase);
}

const submitData = () => {
    let userObj = {
        userName: newData.username,
        password: newData.email,
        id: newData.id
    }

    //it is showing undefined as you have not initialized database with any value, here an array
    dataBase.push(userObj);
}

handleInputs();
```